# Responsive column heights within Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, css, responsive

I have a problem of which I am almost certain it needs javascript but a little baffled on where to begin, anyone with any helpful pointers, I am keen to hear.

I have two columns, copy content in the left and a scalable image in the right.

I would like to:

col-right-image height = 100vh
col-left-content overflow-y = scroll

unless

col-left-content fits in viewport height

then

col-right-image height = col-left-content height

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) and set the maximum height to 100vh. When defining the overflow for the content, it will display a scrollbar.

I have used background colors to visualize the space used for each block.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.image {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  <div class="image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></div>
</div>
```

Whenever the maximum height is not used, is claims the space that's needed.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.image {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  <div class="image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></div>
</div>
```